# Select node by attribute name through XSL in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, xslt, xpath

I'm trying to select a node by its attribute name, but my selectors return nothing.

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<products>
    <product ID="10036218">
    <name>TEST</name>
    <price currency="EUR">8.95</price>
    <categories>
        <category path="Feestartikelen">Feestartikelen</category>
    </categories>
    <properties>
        <property name="fromPrice">
            <value>8.95</value>
        </property>
        <property name="gender">
            <value></value>
        </property>
        <property name="deliveryCosts">
            <value>3.95</value>
        </property>
        <property name="model">
            <value>Balloons</value>
        </property>
    </properties>
    <variations/>
    </product>  
</products> 


Dim nodeList As XmlNodeList = root.SelectNodes("/products/product")
```

nodelist.Count = 530 here, so I'm getting results.
Next I tried both `properties/property/@model/value` and `properties/property/@model` as values to select the node. Both return nothing.

```
For Each node In nodeList
    If node.SelectSingleNode("properties/property/@model/value") IsNot Nothing Then

    End If
Next node
```

What's wrong with my expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you the node by attribute `name`:

```
For Each node In nodeList
    If node.SelectSingleNode("properties/property[@name='model']/value") IsNot Nothing Then

    End If
Next node
```